# How to remove unused .dlls from blazor webassembly publishing(without manually modifying blazor.boot.json etc)

Tags: c#, blazor

We upgraded our old netstandard 2 blazor webassembly app to net 5 recently but the number of dlls in the publish folder went from 43 (netstandard 2) to 181 (net 5). At first I thought it was because I added JSON.NET as a package dependency.... but even after removing and creating an "empty" blazor webassembly, I noticed that there were the same 181 dlls in the publish folder ...(almost like self-contained but it's not)

The total download size has doubled and takes wayyyy longer for all those .dlls to finish downloading making it almost unusable.

Old:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fh9L.png)

New: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTsj9.png)

PublishProfile:

```
 <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>true</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\net5.0\browser-wasm\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <PublishDir>bin\PublishOut\</PublishDir>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>d1f52af3-75a6-43ab-aba9-961d4460413a</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I started to go through and manually verify each .dlls actual usage and remove it from blazor.boot.json, etc, but that is going to take way too long.

I saw in other threads the recommendation for

`<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>true</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>` into the .csproj file
but that didn't work for me.

How can I limit the publish to only include used .dlls?

**[UPDATE]:** I just went ahead and created a console app that runs post publish and removes all unused .dlls from _framework folder and from blazor.boot.json. This got it back down to ~60 dlls vs. 181 and 6mb vs 18mb so much quicker..but still takes about 25 seconds to complete all download the first time run. Yikes. There has to be a better / more correct way to do this , but will have to do until I learn what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: Did you actually do a Publish or just a Release build?  I see ~35 DLLs in the CLient folder after publishing. Plain vanilla WebAssembly Hosted app.

Comment: And just looked at your pictures: Sytem.Windows and WindowsBase.dll ?  Something is very wrong there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, it was a publish (vs a release build)... get the same result from both manual publish from menu or command line dotnet publish.  I did go and create empty blazor webassembly and now getting the ~35 dlls and roughly 2mb publish output so I'll try to rebuild my project from a new empty to see what was is/was triggering all those dependencies. Appreciate your feedback

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I haven't counted my DLL's, but it's sending things like Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll to the browser - they're totally unnecessary!!

Comment: we ended up reverting to targeting .NET Standard 2.1 (instead of 5) and the dll count in the publish folder returned to an expected number

Answer (score 0):

This may be it:

`<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>`

That `False` actually means this `True`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alamakanambra for the suggestion. I had high hopes for this, but I'm still getting all 181 .dlls in the publish folder (even ones like Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll which I know aren't used). Back to manually removing one at a time to see if I get an exception! sigh..